# Problem to calculate values from 1 table using group by in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a logic problem to calculate the final value of this table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPXXX.png

I need calculate for every row with column `TIPO` having the value "E" +1 and for "S" -1, grouping by columns `Codigo` and `Configuracao`.

Basically, I need a simple stock control, the columns `Codigo` and `Configuracao` is product column control, and `TIPO` is the type of moviment, S = OUT and E = IN

Anyone can give me a light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add that +1/-1 column, perhaps?

```
alter table MyTable 
  add tipo_val computed by
  (  
    decode( upper(TIPO), 'E', +1, 'S', -1 )
  )
```

See

- [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-alter)
- [`DECODE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-conditional.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-decode)

And then:

```
Select * from MyTable;

Select SUM(tipo_val), CODIGO, CONFIGURACAO
From MyTable
Group by 2, 3
```

P.S. do not use pictures to show your data.

Instead put them to http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0 as a script,
and then use Markdown Export there to copy both data and a hyperlink into your question text.

P.P.S. I believe your whole approach is wrong there, if "need a simple stock control".

- [Double-entry bookkeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping)
- [Double Entry Accounting in a Relational Database](https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/double-entry-accounting-in-a-relational-database-2b7838a5d7f8)

I think your table should have columns like that:

- surrogate row id, `primary key`, auto-incrementing integer, 32-bits or 64-bits
- columns identifying your item, usually it is, again, a single surrogate integer SKU (Stock Keeping Unit) referencing (see - Foreign Keys) another "dictionary table". In your case it seems to be two columns `Codigo` and `Configuracao` but that also means you can not add extra information ("attributes") about your items, like price or photo (read: database normalization). It also makes grouping harder for Firebird engine, than using a single integer column. Also, you did created an `index` on the item-identifying column(s) did you not? What is your **query plan** on those selects, do they use index on `Codigo` and `Configuracao` or an ad hoc external sorting instead?
- the `timestamp` of an operation, that is automatically set by the Firebird server to be `current_timestamp`, so you always know when exactly that row was inserted. Indexed, of course.
- the computer user who added that row, again, automatically set by Firebird server to `current_user` or to an ID of a user in some `stock_workers` table you would create. Surely, indexed too.
- some description of an operation, like contract number, or seller name, anything that would help you later to remember what real world event that row even describes. Being free form text, it probable would not be indexed. But maybe you would eventually make some `contracts` or `sellers` table and add integer references (FK IDs) to those tables? That depends which exactly kind of data would be repeated often enough to be worth extracting into an extra indexed columns.
- maybe a unit measure, maybe all your units forever would only be measured in pieces, in integer quantity. But maybe there would be some items measured in kilograms, meters, liters, etc?
- finally two integer (or float?) columns like `Qty_Income` and `Qty_Outcome`, where you would record how many items were added or taken from your depot. There would be **not** that E/S column! There would be two integer columns, that you would put number into one or another. Why? read the articles about bookkeeping above!

In such a *database scheme* your query would finally look like this:

```
select Sum(s.Qty_Income) as Credit, Sum(s.Qty_Outcome) as Debit,
       Sum(s.Qty_Income) - Sum(s.Qty_Outcome) as Saldo,
       min(g.Codigo), min(g.Configuracao)
from stock_movements s
       join known_goods g on g.ID = s.SKU_ID 
group by s.SKU_ID
```

And you would also be able to flexibly compose similar requests grouping by workers, or dates, or quantities (like, only care about BIG events  like 1000 or more items added in one operation), or anything.

Answer (score 1):

untested but maybe this

```
select SUM(t1.TipoNumeric), t1.CODIGO, t1.CONFIGURACAO from (
   select 
       case (TIPO)
           when 'E' then 1
           when 'S' then -1
           else 0
       end as TipoNumeric,
       CODIGO,
       CONFIGURACAO
   from MyTable
) as t1
group by t1.CODIGO, t1.CONFIGURACAO
```

Comment: Amazing Rand Random, thx a lot for the help <3

Comment: There is no need for the derived table: you can move the `CASE` into `SUM`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - wasn't sure of it, thought it would complain that TIPO needs to be in group clause.

Comment: No, because `TIPO` is inside the `SUM` that shouldn't happen.